# Does DNS CAA policy applies to all sub domains?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, dns

I get following [DNS CAA](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6844) record for google.com using Google public DNS server

```
google.com. CAA 0 issue "symantec.com"
```

For [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and mail.google.com I **do not** see DNS CAA record. Does above CAA record applies for all sub domains of google.com?

Can any other CA (apart from "symantec.com") that supports CAA would issue certificate for mail.google.com ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does above CAA record applies for all sub domains of google.com?

All subdomains that do not specify `CAA` records of their own.

See, for example, the example in [section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6844#section-3):

```
The following example is a DNS zone file (see [RFC1035]) that informs
CAs that certificates are not to be issued except by the holder of
the domain name 'ca.example.net' or an authorized agent thereof.
This policy applies to all subordinate domains under example.com.

$ORIGIN example.com
.       CAA 0 issue "ca.example.net"
```

And the lookup algorithm in [section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6844#section-4).

If, for example, `mail.google.com` had its own `CAA` record (it currently doesn't), that record would apply to requests for certificates for `mail.google.com`.

> Can any other CA (apart from "symantec.com") that supports CAA would issue certificate for mail.google.com ?

If their DNS queries are successful and they strictly follow the CAA policy, no. As it currently stands, few CAs implement CAA, and some consider CAA more what you'd call guidelines than actual rules, and flag certificates for extra scrutiny, but don't out and out reject issuance.

Regarding your specific example of `mail.google.com`, any halfway competent CA has `google.com` on its VIP list and flags requests for certificates, rejecting them outright or making doubly damn sure they're valid. It's very unlikely a random CA would misissue -- or issue at all -- a `google.com` certificate unless their validation systems were compromised or people had guns to their heads.